# Search data in FireBase for Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to search for data from the database with multiple entered fields.
The fields include `FirstName`, `LastName` and `OtherNames`.
From what I have so far, I can search with either of them with this code:

```
var data =snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
String name = "";
if (data["FirstName"].toString().startsWith(name.toString()) ||
    data["LastName"].toString().startsWith(name.toString()) ||
    data["OtherNames"].toString().startsWith(name.toString())){}
```

But I can't search with multiple fields.
I want to add the logic where the user can search not using only one of the fields, but can also search with multiple fields with spaces in between each field.

Let's say I a user's first name is Mary and the last name is Jane. So I type in "Mary". There could be a million people by the first name Mary using my app. So they all appear. So in this case I want to bring a space and type the Last name as well. In this case I type "Mary Jane". I want to see Mary Jane in the list. But with what I have, immediately I insect the space bar, I don't get the list anymore. I can only do that with only one field at a time.

Is it possible this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*data* has a *Map<String, dynamic>* type, to search with multiple words:

1. Separate your search text (*name*) into words using split

   List searchTerms = name.split(" ");
2. Finally, check if the list of terms contains one of the 3 fields, for example for the firstName field

   searchTerms.contains(data["FirstName"].toString())

**Demo**

if name is "Mary Jane", searchTerms will contain "Mary and Jane".

Does searchTerms contain Mary? => Yes

That will also work for "Misty Jane" for example.

**Code**

```
String name = "John Smith";
List searchTerms = name.split(" ");

if (searchTerms.contains(data["FirstName"].toString()) || searchTerms.contains(data["LastName"].toString())
      || searchTerms.contains(data["OtherNames"].toString())) {
    print("Found");
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

To adapt it to work even if the text is not complete like for "Mary Jan" for example, you can use the *any* method on the *searchTerms* like this:

```
if (
      searchTerms.any((element) => data["FirstName"].toString().startsWith(element))
     || searchTerms.any((element) => data["LastName"].toString().startsWith(element))
     || searchTerms.any((element) => data["OtherNames"].toString().startsWith(element))
    ) {
    print("Found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This has actually shortened my code. But it hasn't solved what I wanted. Let's say I want a user's first name is Mary, So I type in "Mary". There could be a million people by the first name Mary. So they all appear. So in this case I want to bring a space and type the Last name as well. In this case I type "Mary Jane". I wan to see Mary Jane in the list. But what with what I have, immediately I insect the space bar, I don't get the list anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But a little problem. The typed names appear only after I have fully typed it in the textBox. Can it be made in such a way that the names appear as I type. For example with "data["FirstName"].toString().startsWith(name.toString())", the names appear as you type. But with "searchTerms.contains(data["FirstName"].toString())", the names come only after u fully finish typing. Can it be changed

Comment: You  can use "any", check the update section of the answer thank you.

Comment: Thank a lot. That helps